# How to successfully get all src of image nested under span tag using Selenium in Python

Tags: python, selenium

I'm trying to scrape articles on a website. And would like to get the src of images. I had a good go at it with a few attempts and my code can't seem to fetch all these src.

I am using Selenium 3.141.0 with Python 3.7.
There are 4 things that I want to get: src of images, link to full article, headline, article snippet. 
I can scrape the rest successfully but not the src.
I want to dump all of these details into a pandas dataframe.

This is the code of the website I'm trying to scrape.

```
<article class="w29" data-minarticles="1.00">
    <a href="something.html">
        <figure class="left ">
            <span class="img-a is-loaded">
                <img alt="stock image" title="stock image" width="245" height="135" src="pic.JPG" class="">
                <noscript>
                  "<img src="pic.JPG" alt="stock image" title="stock image" width="245" height="135" />"
                </noscript>
             </span>
          </figure>
        <h2>
            <span>
            Article Title
            </span>
        </h2>
        <p>
          "Article snippet"
        </p>
      </a>
      ::after
</article>
<article class="w29" data-minarticles="1.00">
    <a href="something2.html">
        <figure class="left ">
            <span class="img-a is-loaded">
                <img alt="stock image2" title="stock image2" width="245" height="135" src="pic2.JPG" class="">
                <noscript>
                  "<img src="pic2.JPG" alt="stock image2" title="stock image2" width="245" height="135" />"
                </noscript>
             </span>
          </figure>
        <h2>
            <span>
            Article Title 2
            </span>
        </h2>
        <p>
          "Article snippet 2"
        </p>
      </a>
</article>
<article class="w29" data-minarticles="1.00">
    <a href="something3.html">
        <figure class="left ">
            <span class="img-a is-loaded">
                <img alt="stock image3" title="stock image3" width="245" height="135" src="pic3.JPG" class="">
                <noscript>
                  "<img src="pic3.JPG" alt="stock image3" title="stock image3" width="245" height="135" />"
                </noscript>
             </span>
          </figure>
        <h2>
            <span>
            Article Title 3
            </span>
        </h2>
        <p>
          "Article snippet 3"
        </p>
      </a>
</article>
```

And this is my code:

```
driver.get(url)

# get sub posts
sub_posts = driver.find_elements_by_class_name("w29")

# get details
sub_list = []
for post in sub_posts:
    # Get the link to the full article
    sub_source = post.find_element_by_tag_name('a').get_attribute('href')
    # Get the src of the post 
    sub_photo = post.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')
    # Get headline
    sub_headline = post.find_element_by_tag_name('h2').text
    # Get article snippet
    sub_snippet = post.find_element_by_tag_name('p').text
    sub_list.append([sub_photo, sub_source, sub_headline, sub_snippet])

post_df = pd.DataFrame(sub_list, columns=["photo", "source", "headline", "snippet"])
```

This is what I have tried and the result that I got in the dataframe, focusing on line of code to get the src of the post:

**Attempt 1**

`sub_photo = post.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src')`

**Result of Attempt 1**

For whatever reason, it scraped the first src and returns None for the rest of the articles.

```
photo      source           headline         snippet
pic.JPG    something.html   Article Title    Article Snippet
None       something2.html  Article Title 2  Article Snippet 2
None       something3.html  Article Title 3  Article Snippet 3
```

**Attempt 2**

```
sub_photo = post.find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="content"]/div[6]/div[1]/div[2]/article/a/figure/span/img').get_attribute('src')
```

**Result of Attempt 2**

It scraped the first src and returns the same, first src to the rest of the articles.

```
photo      source           headline         snippet
pic.JPG    something.html   Article Title    Article Snippet
pic.JPG    something2.html  Article Title 2  Article Snippet 2
pic.JPG    something3.html  Article Title 3  Article Snippet 3
```

**Attempt 3**

```
sub_photo = post.find_element_by_css_selector('a>figure>span>img').get_attribute('innerHTML')
```

**Result of Attempt 3**

It scraped the first innerHTML and return the same, first innerHTML for the rest of the articles.

```
photo       source           headline         snippet
\n<img...   something.html   Article Title    Article Snippet
\n<img...   something2.html  Article Title 2  Article Snippet 2
\n<img...   something3.html  Article Title 3  Article Snippet 3
```

This is what I'm looking for:

```
photo      source           headline         snippet
pic.JPG    something.html   Article Title    Article Snippet
pic2.JPG   something2.html  Article Title 2  Article Snippet 2
pic3.JPG   something3.html  Article Title 3  Article Snippet 3
```

Would appreciate if someone can point me to the right direction. Thank you.

Comment: Do you need to scroll page down to see all images?

Comment: Is there an URL we can use ?

Comment: @JaSON yes I have to scroll down

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Initially only couple images are rendered, so you can either scroll page to the bottom to extract all `@src` values or you can extract `@src` (for visible images) OR `@data-src` (for hidden images):

```
sub_photo = post.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('src') or post.find_element_by_tag_name('img').get_attribute('data-src')
```

This will return you the value of `@src` if it's not `None` OR the value of `@data-src` if `@src` is `None`

Comment: Thanks @JaSON . Didn't know about @data-src!

Answer (score 1):

For the first post the data is in the src attribute but then is in the data-src (in your code). See the following for example

```
for post in sub_posts:   
    ele = post.find_element_by_tag_name('img')
    val = ele.get_attribute('data-src') if ele.get_attribute('data-src') is not None else ele.get_attribute('src')
    print(val)
```

Comment: Actually ternary condition operator implementation is just more complicated version of my code with `or` operator

Comment: @JaSON I am new to python and wasn't aware I could shortcut with Or. +1 for you

Comment: In `a = 0 or None or [] or "" or 1` expression the first value that can be evaluated to `True`  will be assigned (so `a` will be `1`)